# Fastest way to perform same operation on every element of array

Tags: python, multithreading, iterator

I have an array of dimensions 100x100x1000. For every pixel of the array, I want to perform the following operation:

```
A = np.random.rand(100, 100, 1000)
values = [[0, 1, 2, 3],
          [0, 2, 4, 5],
          [3, 0, 1, 2],
          [4, 3, 3, 0]]
vmax = np.amax(values)
for i in range(A.shape[0]-2):
    for j in range(A.shape[1]-2):
        for v in values:
            for t in A.shape[2] - vmax:
                result[i,j] = A[i+1, j, t+v[0]] * A[i, j+1, t+v[1]] * A[i+2, j+1, t+v[2]] * A[i+1, j+2, t+v[3]]
```

I wrote the code as inefficiently as I could just to make it clear that it's basically 4 nested loops for every single pixel. The most efficient way I've found is by indexing and multiplying:

```
A = np.random.rand(100, 100, 1000)
    values = [[0, 1, 2, 3],
              [0, 2, 4, 5],
              [3, 0, 1, 2],
              [4, 3, 3, 0]]
result = np.zeros((98, 98))
for v in values:
    result += A[-1:1, :-2, v[0]:-vmax+v[0]] * A[:-2, 1:-1, v[1]:-vmax+v[1]] * A[-2:, 1:-1, v[2]:-vmax+v[2]] * A[-1:1, 2:, v[3]:-vmax+v[3]]
```

However, even this method can be extremely time-consuming for long combinations of "values" or for larger arrays "A". Are there any other approaches that could speed this up? My knowledge of multiprocessing is quite limited so I don't know if it would yield faster results than numpy's multiplications.
Or since the operation is always the same, is there a more efficient way to vectorise the operation?

Comment: Your code looks good, nothing stands out as a bottleneck. You do perform 10 million iterations with a lot of calculation at each iteration, this would naturally take a bit of time. This is called a CPU-bound task, common way to speed it up is multiprocessing. It WILL make it faster. Roughly speaking speed up factor is your physical cores amount. You could also profile your code to see slow points.

Comment: try [cupy](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/), it has similar syntax to numpy